# Is there a way to get the day of the week, month and year in one statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using Microsoft server management studio. I am currently getting what I need by using multiple statements but I was wondering if there was a better cleaner way to do it. I need to get the day of the month, the day name (Monday), month, and the year.

```
  DATENAME(WEEKDAY, f.DepartDateTime) + ', ' +

  DATENAME(MONTH, f.DepartDateTime) + ' ' +

  DATENAME(DAY , f.DepartDateTime) + 

  IIF(DATENAME(DAY, f.DepartDateTime) IN (1,21,31), 'st', 
   
IIF(DATENAME(DAY, f.DepartDateTime) IN (2,22), 'nd', 
  
IIF(DATENAME(DAY, f.DepartDateTime) IN (3,23), 'rd', 'th'))) + ', ' +

DATENAME(YEAR, f.DepartDateTime) + ' at ' +

DATENAME(HOUR, f.DepartDateTime) +  ':' +

DATENAME(MINUTE, f.DepartDateTime) + '. '  +
```

I guess i'm wondering if there is a function, like DATENAME that will take more than one parameter at a time.

This is what i have and it works, but i'm still learning and was wondering if there was a better way. !!This is for a past homework assignment.

Comment: `format()` if by "parameter" you seek various output options.

Comment: That is one **statement** containing multiple **expressions**. TSQL is not intended for "pretty" reporting or converting numbers into commonly used terms. And beware that FORMAT is an expensive operation that can affect performance. TBH - sql is generally not used in this fashion - do not draw the wrong lesson from this assignment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use convert function to get different output format as below.

```
select CONVERT(varchar(20),getdate(),101)
select CONVERT(varchar(20),getdate(),106)
```

For more format options refer the [link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT FORMAT (f.DepartDateTime, 'dddd, dd-MMM-yyyy') as FormattedDepartDate
```

[sql format tutorial](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2655/format-sql-server-dates-with-format-function/)
[sql format fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=185a0c1131629bd978f225abbaf9c860)